# Обработка ошибки в yii

Tags: yii

Обработка ошибки в yii 
В config/main.php прописан путь к обработке ошибки 'errorAction' => 'error/index' . Соответсвенно создан Контроллер Error с действием Index:
Котроллер.

```
class ErrorController extends Controller{
/**
 * This is the action to handle external exceptions.
 */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        if ($error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                echo $error['message'];
            else
                $this->render('index', $error);
        }
    } 
}
```

В свою очередь у класса Controller прописано:

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    protected function beforeAction($action)
    {
        Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();
        $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
        $cs->registerCssFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl . '/css/style.css');
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

И т.д.

По идее, При обработке ошибки должны подключаться css-стили через  beforeAction, но этого почему-то не происходит, хотя если beforeAction добавить в сам котррллер ErrorController, то всё начинает работать и стили подключаются.

Comment: @Александр Железновский, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте для ErrorController задать тот-же layout что и для SiteController.

Comment: Он и так тот же

Comment: Тогда подключайте css в layout-е, или во вьюве. Подключать стили имеет смысл именно там.

Comment: этот совет я конечно учту, хоть он и весьма спорный, но вопрос в том, почему не работает, а не что делать. Был бы опытнее, я бы нашел ответ сам. А так это некая внутренняя фишка устройства yii

Comment: А чего тут спорить? В обобщенном случае стили нужны только если рендерится view, соответственно, их подключение логично делать именно там. Ведь, в том же самом обобщенном случае, контроллер может отдавать json для аякс запросов, может делать редирект. В этих ситуациях стили не нужны. А у вас, через beforeAction, стиль подключается всегда.

> но вопрос в том, почему не работает

Сложно сказать, у вас стиль подключается перед `parent::beforeAction($action)`. Возможно где-то на уровень ниже делается очистка для `clientScript`. Попробуйте подключить css после вызова parent-метода.